# What is the current status of hbase 2.0?

Tags: hbase

I see [2.0.0-snapshot](http://hbase.apache.org/) at official site, but documentation refered to 0.94 (from site menu). Does it ready for usage or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation referes to 2.0.0-snapshot as well - http://hbase.apache.org/book.html (that's the link right to the 0.94 documentation). The reason for both is that there were major changes when HBase 1.0 came out. In any event the latest release (as of July 2015) is still 1.1.1 release Jun 29th you can see the releases here: http://apache.spd.co.il/hbase/

Generally speaking in Java projects the convention is that SNAPSHOT releases are not final

Comment: Thanks, but when do they plan to release 2.0 version?

Comment: To see hbase release plans you should follow the HBase dev mailing list http://hbase.apache.org/mail-lists.html